# GCM push notification not working , and register id is also not displaying

Tags: java, android, jsp

I have written a program for GCM to register and share the registered id to a new activity , but unfortunately my register id is itself not showing when i click on register button and when i click on send push notification button on jsp page it throws me an error which says **`"File Not Found Exception GCMRegId.txt"`** .
 If someone can suggest me the changes that i have to make to the following code , it would be of great help

GCMNotification.java

```
@WebServlet("/GCMNotification")
public class GCMNotification extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Put your Google API Server Key here
private static final String GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY = "Server Key";
static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "message";

public GCMNotification() {
super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {
doPost(request, response);

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException,
    IOException {

Result result = null;

String share = request.getParameter("shareRegId");

// GCM RedgId of Android device to send push notification
String regId = "";
if (share != null && !share.isEmpty()) {
    regId = request.getParameter("regId");
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("GCMRegId.txt");
    writer.println(regId);
    writer.close();
    request.setAttribute("pushStatus", "GCM RegId Received.");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
} else {

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("GCMRegId.txt"));
        regId = br.readLine();
        br.close();
        String userMessage = request.getParameter("message");
        Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
        Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30).delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData(MESSAGE_KEY, userMessage).build();
        System.out.println("regId: " + regId);
        result = sender.send(message, regId, 1);
        request.setAttribute("pushStatus", result.toString());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        request.setAttribute("pushStatus", "RegId required: " + ioe.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        request.setAttribute("pushStatus", e.toString());
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
   }
  }
```

**`RegistrationActivity.java`** which has two button one for Registering and other for sharing, `On register button` i have put a toast but when i click on it , it shows me `"RegId is : " , no regid is shown` and when i click on share button , it shows **`"RegId is empty"`**

```
public class RegisterGCMActivity extends Activity {
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
Context context;
String registerId;
Button btnGCMRegister;
Button btnAppShare;

public static final String REG_ID = "regId";
private static final String APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
String passedData;
TextView txtHeader;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.reg_gcm);
txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
passedData = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
txtHeader.setText(passedData);

context = getApplicationContext();

btnGCMRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReg);
btnGCMRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(registerId)) {
            registerId = registerGCM();
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "GCM RegId: " + registerId);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "RegId is :" + registerId, 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
             "Already Registered with GCM Server!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
       }
    });

btnAppShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShare);
btnAppShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(registerId)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RegId is empty!", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service_Access.class);
            i.putExtra("regId", registerId);
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", 
             "onClick of Share: Before starting main activity.");
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "onClick of Share: After finish.");
          }
         }
     });
    }

public String registerGCM() {

gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
registerId = getRegistrationId(context);

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(registerId)) {

    registerInBackground();

    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "registerGCM - successfully registered with GCM server - regId:
    " + registerId);
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RegId already available. RegId: " + registerId, 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
return registerId;
}

private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String registrationId = prefs.getString(REG_ID, "");
if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
    // Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
    return "";
}
int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
    // Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
    return "";
}
return registrationId;
}

private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = 
    context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    return packageInfo.versionCode;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "I never expected this! Going down, going down!" + e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
 }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void registerInBackground() {
new AsyncTask() {
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String msg = "";
        try {
            if (gcm == null) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
            }
            registerId = gcm.register(com.android.d_governance.Config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "registerInBackground - regId: " + registerId);
            msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + registerId;

            storeRegistrationId(context, registerId);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Error: " + msg);
        }
        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "AsyncTask completed: " + msg);
        return msg;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered with GCM Server." + msg, 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
      }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
   }

private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Service_Access.class.getSimpleName(),
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(REG_ID, regId);
editor.putInt(APP_VERSION, appVersion);
editor.commit();
}
```

GCMNotificationIntentService.java

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
    if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
        sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
    } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
        sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
    } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            // Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ " +
            // SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

        }
        // Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " +
        // SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

        sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server: " +  
        extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY));
        // Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
    }
}
GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
 }

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
// Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, 
Service_Access.class), 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new  
NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_logo)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification").setStyle(new 
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
// Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
  }
```

Config.java

```
public interface Config {
// GCM server using java
static final String APP_SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.1.17:8081/GCM-App-Server/GCMNotification? 
shareRegId=1";

// Google Project Number
static final String GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID = "167543534432";
static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "message";
}
```

When i click on the button push notification via GCM from index.jsp page , this is the error it shows

java.io.FileNotFoundException: GCMRegId.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.d_governance.GCMNotification.doPost(GCMNotification.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

My LogCat :

01-12 12:05:07.765: D/RegisterActivity(20445): registerGCM - successfully registered with GCM server - regId: 
01-12 12:05:07.765: D/RegisterActivity(20445): GCM RegId:

No GCM RegId is showing up

Please need some help in displaying my regid 
Thanking You

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace?

Comment: @shyam i have updated my question with logcat and the error it is showing

Comment: As far as I can see, you haven't sent the registered GCM ID from the android app to your application server, have you?

Comment: yes sir , but to send my regid , it should at least get displayed in my toast message , and i also debugged and checked , my regid is returning null
You can check here sir , this is the reference (http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/)  , i have implemented the same

Answer (score 0):

Use this method instead of getRegistrationId();

```
private String getRegistrationId(Context context) 
    {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId=="") 
        {
            registerInBackground();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"RegId already available. RegId: " + registrationId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) 
        {
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }
```

Comment: sir i am always getting an error saying File Not Found Exception , GCMRegId.txt not found , what to do ?

Comment: Arjun - You need to use actual value of GCM RegID and not just a keyword RegID. So RegID is 4K bytes of alphanumeric value